# Add Column Count in mapped set of card

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

This is my code:

```js
this.props.sensors.map((sensor) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <Card.Group>
                  <Card>
                    <Card.Content>
                      <Card.Header>Hi</Card.Header>
                   </Card.Content>
                  </Card>
                </Card.Group>
              </div>
            );
         });
```

Mapped in my array object and add to the card. its all are running well. but the documentation says add `itemsPerRow={4}` to `Card.Group`. But in this situation we cannot add this. can you please help me to resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to use `sensor` inside `map`'s callback?

Comment: Please let us know why you cannot add it. It is not clear what exactly you want to do and where you are getting stuck on.

Comment: @GalAbra I added sample card code. I use the sensor on the card.

Comment: In this situation, cards adding like Vertically. Because every card has this card.Group. so they add cards vertically.  my question is, how can i add itemsPerRow={4}  in to (card.Group). also I tried to get (Card.Group and Card)  out of map. but its not working.